# Router reboots itself after ~20 minutes of work: how do I fix that?

Tags: networking, router

Here is my setup: an industrial enterprise, a dozen computers at office, a file NAS which synchronizes often, industrial machines (large ones, possibly emiting EMP fields), multiple IP cameras. There is a main router - Netis WF2419 (DHCP is enabled, connected to the Internet), and a TP Link router of a similar price is connected to it (DHCP is disabled, working as WIFI relay for another workshop. I have configured WiFi segments, they do not overlap). Both were purchased in ~2015-2016. For some reason, the provider then ran an optical fiber to the workshop (incoming connection > Media converter> optical fiber> Media converter> Router> our infrastructure).

My problem is: Netis WF2419 router started to reboot regularly - it works for about 20 minutes, then restarts itself. According to statistics it processes about 1000000 Kbytes of data during that time, but CPU load is on ~10%, mem load is on ~5% (it does not seem much for router). I am adding statistics, on shutdown:
[image: statistics of router on shutdown]

I have checked articles regarding this problem:

https://kb.netgear.com/30858/How-do-I-troubleshoot-intermittent-rebooting-of-a-router

https://ru.ifixit.com/Answers/View/629913/Why+does+my+router+randomly+restart

Electrician assured that power supply is stable, all other company equipment is working. The key point here is a 'fixed' period of work - 20 minutes.

Intuitively I assume that fixing this via software or configuration is probably unlikely.

What may be a solution of this problem? Is buying new router a viable solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You make a good point stating there are large industrial machines, possibly creating electromagnetic interference (EMI) or radio-frequency interference (RFI). Though the AC mains may be *stable*, that does not mean they're *clean*, without RF on the line. EMI can also be picked up by cables, even *shielded* cable, if the EMI is sufficiently powerful.

To prove whether it's the router itself at fault, or external interference causing the issue, you might have to go through a painstaking process of elimination.

- Put the router in a shielded box (Faraday cage), with all connections either through [Ethernet RFI suppressors](https://www.mouser.com/new/murata/murata-noise-suppression-ethernet-100base-t1/), RF-suppressing [USB isolators](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07QKYYCD8), AC mains [noise suppressors](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07HZ4RSS7), etc. No line or opening should be left in the enclosure without suppression! *N.B.: Links are for illustration, not for recommendation.*
- Put a small [online UPS](https://ehomerecordingstudio.com/uninterruptible-power-supplies/) inside the enclosure for just the router.
- Input to the router should be through isolated optical fiber.
- Temporarily disconnect any cables leading to the router running past large machines.
- Keep a log of router issues **and of heavy equipment startup**. Does the issue occur when machines are down for maintenance and off-time?

Comment: Yes, router keeps restarting when machines are turned off. It started yesterday though, and of course I was notified about it

Comment: Well, you've eliminated one idea. My first thought would be to try an inexpensive UPS with RFI filter, perhaps one on hand, to see if that helps, It should be very quick and simple to test, at least.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, an old router turned off completely. Guess, that was hardware issue.  We purchased new router - and that solved a question. Anyway, thanks for advices about placing of routers in industrial environment

Comment: If the failure of the router leads to a lot of expense (e.g., missed orders or upset customers) then it would be a good idea to have a spare router in case the same thing happens again.